# Автоматически удалять пустые строки в DataGreedView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]
[image]

Как сделать так, чтобы строки из DataGreedView автоматически удалялись, если в них стерли данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataGreedView имеет множество событий.

Тебе подойдет событие [RowLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave(v=vs.110).aspx) . Подписываешься на это событие и в обработчике события реализуешь нужную тебе логику, в данном случае пробегаешься по строке и проверяешь ее на пустоту. Если он целиком пустая, то удаляешь.